# is there a way to reduce the commands to execute a node application installed from npm

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, package

I made a small npm package and deployed it, basically it's a CLI tool built in node, and I am trying to reduce the commands needed to execute it

So far, to use the CLI, I follow this steps :
-> npm install my_package (obviously)
-> cd node_modules/my_package
-> `node index.js`

running `node node_modules/my_package/index.js` doesn't give the expected outcome because I use **PropertyReader** to read from a **.properties** file and if i don't run the CLI from the folder containing this file, I end up with an error of ***'no such file or directory'***

this is the structure of the package

```
/node_modules
|__ /my_package
    |__ index.js
    |__ my.properties
```

Part of my index.js to help :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

properties = PropertiesReader('./my.properties');
```

the perfect scenario would be to install the package and run one command to launch my CLI, any suggestion or ideas that can help are welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked the proposed solution to fit my needs by relying on [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) to get the absolute path of my **index.js**, the locate the property file from it

```
const path = require("path");
var dirpath = path.resolve(__dirname);
properties = PropertiesReader(path.join(dirpath, "my.properties"));
```

Now i still have to find a way to replace the command : `node node_modules/my_package/index.js` with something like `start my_package` or just `my_package`, which BTW works by default when i install my_package globally (**npm install -g my_package**) ( I just run `my_package` in the CMD and it works!)

Does someone has an idea how to reproduce this behavior even when I'm installing it locally?

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer assumes you are on a Unix-style operating system like Linux or OSX.

Typically, you create a runnable command somewhere in your project directory and use `npm link` to link it into `./node_modules/.bin` (or to your global executable directory.)

If you chose to keep the command with your project (rather than installing it globally), it's important to make sure your PATH includes `./node_modules/.bin` ( as in: `export PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH`) so you can invoke your new CLI.

See [A guide to creating a NodeJS command-line package](https://medium.com/netscape/a-guide-to-create-a-nodejs-command-line-package-c2166ad0452e) for a complete solution.

Finally, if you wish to reference resources relative to your installation directory, you'd need to load them using [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) to convert a relative path to an absolute one, like: `var res = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../config/file'))` where `__dirname` represents the directory in which your CLI lives.

So assuming:

```
./
  index.js
  package.json
  bin/
    cli
  config/
    my.properties
```

in `./bin/cli`, you would:

```
const path=require('path')
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader')
const properties_file_path = path.resolve(__dirname, '../config/my.properties')
const properties = PropertiesReader(properties_file_path)
```

Comment: Actually I'm using a windows machine,

and I'm trying to find a way to locate the property file relativly to index.js and not to where I executed node,

my idea is to get the absolute path of the index.js ( for ex: C:/data/files/index.js , then I am sure that my property file's path is C:/fata/files/my.properties )

I'm not sure how to do it